# Increasing the spacing between Items in ListView, Maui/Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mvvm, maui

I am trying to create a simple ListView with custom ItemTemplate which consists of a Grid with some information. Each item in the ListView should have a larger space than that of the default. I've tried messing around with Margins/Padding but can't seem to create a larger space between items.
Does anyone have any tips how to achieve a greater whitespace between items in a ListView? From what I've found online and in documentation seems to be lacking. But there must be something I'm missing since this should be a pretty obvious use case of a ListView.

Code in the xaml page which the user sees:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding List, Mode=TwoWay}"
          VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
          HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          WidthRequest="455"
          SeparatorVisibility="Default"
          SeparatorColor="Transparent"
          BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"
          IsGroupingEnabled="True"
          >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <controls:CustomItemTextTable NameText="Name Name"
                                            IdentityText="NUMBER IDENTITY"
                                            IssuerText="TEST"
                                            IssuerOrganisationText="TEST ORG"
                                            CreatedText="2022-10-10 20:24"
                                            ExpireText="2042-04-06 22:58"
                                            StatusText="Inactive"
                                            TrustLevelText="3"
                                            IsClippedToBounds="False"
                                            />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code in the CustomItemTextTable

```
<Border StrokeThickness="0"
        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10"
        BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
        Padding="11"
        >
 
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="155,10,171"
          RowDefinitions="*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*"
          Padding="0,0,0,0"
          >
        <Label Text="Name"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="0"
               HorizontalOptions="End"
               />
        <Label Text="Identity"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="0"
               HorizontalOptions="End"
               />
        <Label Text="Issuer"
               Grid.Row="2"
               Grid.Column="0"
               HorizontalOptions="End"
               />
        <Label Text="Issuer org"
               Grid.Row="3"
               Grid.Column="0"
               HorizontalOptions="End"
               />
        <Label Text="Created"
               Grid.Row="4"
               Grid.Column="0"
               HorizontalOptions="End"
               />
        <Label Text="Expire"
               Grid.Row="5"
               Grid.Column="0"
               HorizontalOptions="End"
               />
        <Label Text="Status"
               Grid.Row="6"
               Grid.Column="0"
               HorizontalOptions="End"
               />
        <Label Text="TrustLevel"
               Grid.Row="7"
               Grid.Column="0"
               HorizontalOptions="End"
                         />
        <Label Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="2"
               x:Name="name"
               />
        <Label Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="2"
               x:Name="identity"
               />
        <Label Grid.Row="2"
               Grid.Column="2"
               x:Name="issuer"
               />
        <Label Grid.Row="3"
               Grid.Column="2"
               x:Name="issuerOrg"
               />
        <Label Grid.Row="4"
               Grid.Column="2"
               x:Name="created"
               />
        <Label Grid.Row="5"
               Grid.Column="21"
               x:Name="expire"
               />
        <Label Grid.Row="6"
               Grid.Column="2"
               x:Name="status"
               />
        <Label Grid.Row="7"
               Grid.Column="2"
               x:Name="trustLevel"
               />
    </Grid>
```

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated...

I tried increasing Padding/Margin in both Xaml-pages.

Comment: Margin on the item (`CustomItemTextTable`) is the usual fix. Don't know why that isn't working for you. Show some of the xaml for that, including showing exactly where you added `Margin`.

Comment: AFAIK a `ListView` doesn't support something like an item spacing, so you would always need some other trick to do it using that. You could also achieve your goal using a `StackLayout` in combination with a `BindableLayout`, then you have the option to set the `Spacing` property of the `StackLayout`. You won't get a separator between items, though.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve The CustomItemTextTable is a Grid consisting of 2 columns and 8 rows... Maybe using a grid wasnt the smartest? 

I'll edit the question and add the CustomTextTable xaml code

Comment: @ewerspej Ah okay, that seems odd.. Then I might have to redo the design choice

Comment: @trenderkyl13 You could still try with the `ListView` as it has some advantages over my alternative suggestion, such as built-in scrolling. If you need scrolling behavior, you would need to wrap the layout with a `ScrollView` with that approach. Have you tried setting a Margin directly as @ToolkmakerSteve suggested: `CustomItemTextTable Margin="0,10"` (for example)?

Comment: @trenderkyl13 I don't think it's odd that the `ListView` doesn't offer a spacing option. There's a multitude of possibilities here. It may seem odd only when coming from other frameworks like Flutter, I suppose.

Comment: @ewerspej That seems to just push in the context of the Item together but not add more space inbetween items

Comment: @Ewerspej Perhaps, I assume creating a StackLayout with a BindableLayout with spacing is the way to go. Although The ListView does offer the nice benefit of ItemSource as I want to display a variable of items depending on the size of the list

Comment: The `BindableLayout` also has an `ItemsSource`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/bindablelayout?view=net-maui-7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMPORTANT: You don't show the first few lines of CustomItemTextTable's xaml -
The header element that defines `x:Class`. Remove any `BackgroundColor` there, or change it to something obvious like "HotPink", to see if it is filling an area you are trying to make "show through".

---

That XAML doesn't give LayoutManager enough information to do what you want:

- You've told Grid to make all rows same height (`*`), but nowhere is a total height stated.
- Then you ask for a `Margin`, but that gets taken from the default total height assigned to the item.

The safest solution is to explicitly Request a Height. Make it large enough to include the desired Margin:

```xml
<CustomItemTextTable HeightRequest="210" Margin="0,0,0,10" ... />
```

NOTE: An alternative location for HeightRequest and/or Margin is in the custom view's header:

```xml
<SomeUIClass
  xmlns:...
  x:Class="...CustomItemTextTable"
  HeightRequest="210"      <-- these can be above x:Class property if you prefer.
  Margin="0,0,0,10"
/>
```

If that doesn't fix it, remove that Margin. Instead, add a TRANSPARENT area within the item. Thus allowing color behind to show through. There are various ways to do this. Here is one:

```xml
<StackLayout
  <Border ...    <-- your existing code
  </Border>
  <BoxView HeightRequest="10" />
</StackLayout>
```